# Finding the largest rectangle inside a quadrilateral

Tags: algorithm, math

Lately, I've scanned a lot of album covers in an attempt to digitalize my music collection. The default procedure after scanning is rotating and cropping.

For rotating, the important thing is to find one or more lines of reference. After rotating, the 'normal' lines will be more or less horizontal (or vertical) and the odd lines will be somewhat slanted. Two 'different' rotations can be distinguished:

[image: Two quadrilaterals]

NOTE: The two quadrilaterals are two album covers. You can imagine the two lines in the album covers as two printed lines. All the reference lines are in bold. You might wonder why the album covers aren't just rectangles but note that this image is greatly exagerated. That said, if you've ever looked at album covers closely, you'll notice that they're rarely ever close to a rectangle.

In situation A, it is clear that most of the cover edges are parallel and form 90 degree angles, and/or the printed objects are overly slanted which indicates that the print itself is slanted. In both cases I can better use the cover edges as reference.

In situation B, most of the lines seem irregular and the print seems alright. I then better use the printed objects as reference.

All in all, this is mostly an intuitive process.

Although the aforementioned is not part of the actual problem I thought it would be useful for you to know the background info first. We've now arrived at the cropping step, the part that has always bugged me.

My question is simple: If I must crop any album cover, how can I crop it in such a way that it leaves me with the largest portion of the album cover? Put differently, how can I find the 4 values that together form the largest possible rectangle inside a quadrilateral?

The only condition is that the rectangle must be parallel to the reference lines, i.e. horizontal.

Comment: Should the rectangle be aligned with the real-world x and y axis? Or can the rectangle be rotated with respect to the real world?

Comment: The two covers in the image are already rotated, meaning that the reference lines are horizontal, i.e. aligned with the real-world x axis. Since I also want this in my final image, the crop rectangle must also be aligned with the real-world x axis.

Comment: http://cgm.cs.mcgill.ca/~athens/cs507/Projects/2003/DanielSud/

Answer (score -2):

If you accept the constraint that the given rectangle will be aligned with the x and y axis in the real world, and not at some slant, you can do the following

```
Given that point contains values x,y
Given quadrilateral roughly formed by

    A
                  B

      C          D

A rectangle may be formed via the following

leftX = max(A.x,C.x) 
topY = min(A.y,B.y)
rightX = min(B.x,D.x)
botY = max(C.y,D.y)

rectA = point(leftX, topY)
rectB = point(rightX, topY)
rectC = point(leftX, botY)
rectD = point(rightX, botY)
```

Comment: Thanks your answer! Am I right that this will produce 'a' rectangle and not necessarily the largest possible rectangle?

Comment: It occurs to me that it is conceivable that you can increase the size very slightly in some cases by going 'up and over' so to speak. However, the increase will be incredibly small (I estimate at most 2% larger when you consider the target data set).

Comment: It would break down if you were to have something like... Imagine a triangle with the very top cut off, forming a trapezoid. So a very very wide base, and a very very narrow top. The rectangle formed by connecting those two would very small, approaching 0 under the right conditions. Clearly a 'middle of the road' approach in that sense would cause it to be much much larger (on the order of roughly half the area of the trapezoid. But given your examples, my method, in addition to being the simplest, will provide adequate and aesthetic results, even if not most optimal in terms of area.

Comment: You're right, that's basically what I'm aiming for. In the meanwhile, I found this site: http://cgm.cs.mcgill.ca/~athens/cs507/Projects/2003/DanielSud/ It explains an algorithm to do it and offers an applet which doesn't use the algorithm but a brute force solution. Unfortunately the applet is totally graphics based. I don't know how you are at java but perhaps the code can be edit such that values can be in/outputted.